# How to perform multiplication along axes in pytorch?

Tags: python, keras, pytorch

I have 2 tensors X and Y - X has shape (20,4,300) and Y has shape(20,300) . How to perform multiplication such that I have an result of shape (20,4). The corresponding techinique in keras is

```py
doc_product = Dot(axes=(2,1))([X,Y])
```

I would like to know how the same can be done in pytorch?

Comment: `Y[:,None].bmm(X.permute(0,2,1)).squeeze()` or `torch.einsum('ijk,ik->ij', X, Y)`. Please include a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your most versatile function for matrix multiplication is [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html?highlight=einsum): it allows you specify the dimensions along which to multiply and the order of the dimensions of the output tensor.
In your case it would look like:

```py
dot_product = torch.einsum('bij,bj->bi')
```